# Drawing a wake like shape on a frame using tizk

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm here to ask how can I do a wave like shape showed on image below on a beamer frame using tizk:
[image: Example of the frame I wanna do]

I can only make it a straight line. Thanks

Comment: The image is a "frame" so you can imagine some title and author there instead of only a white board e__e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

welcome to TeX-SE.
Use Bezier curve for a shape like this.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,0) --++ (0,1) .. controls ++(7,1) and ++(-2,1) .. ++(10,0) --++ (0,-1) --cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Beziers wave]

Answer (score 2):

You can e.g. draw an arc with `to`  (it needs two compilations). A bezier curve is possible too, check the documentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]

\fill[draw=black,thick,fill=blue] ([yshift=1.5cm]current page.south west) to[in=30,out=50] ([yshift=1.5cm]current page.south east)--
 (current page.south east)--(current page.south west)--cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]